# Is it possible to tail kubernetes pod logs and grep it?

Tags: kubernetes

Now I am running java in kubernetes pods, now I did not deployment fluentd, I have to tail log in the kubernetes dashbooard UI. But now I want to filter the java log using grep in a simple way like this:

```
tail -f service.log | grep "simpe info"
```

Is it possible to do this, in the terminal I just tail the pod's log but I want to tail pod's running service log. Thanks.

Comment: You should be able to do pretty much exactly that with `kubectl logs`, if you don't mind the filtering happening on your local machine (there will be some extra network traffic from lines you're not reading).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run kubectl like as shown below

```
kubectl -n <namespace> exec <pod-name> -- 'tail -f <file-path/file-name> | grep "simpe info"'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this

```
kubectl logs -l app=<app-name> | grep "info"
```

Comment: It's not tail, it dumps all logs and runs grep on them.